# Question on proper choice of test function

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde

Let $\Omega$ be a $\mathcal{C}^2-$compact manifold in $\mathbb R^2$ and consider the non-homogeneous heat equation:
$$
\partial_t v - \Delta v
= f
\quad \text{in } \ \Omega \times (0,T),
$$
where $f \in L^1(\Omega \times (0,T))$.
We can say that $v \in L^1(0,T;W^{1,s}_0(\Omega))$ for $s<2$ is a weak solution if:
\begin{equation*} \tag{$\star$}
-\int_0^T \int_{\Omega} v \partial_t \phi +\int_0^T \int_{\Omega} \nabla v\nabla \phi
= \int_0^T \int_{\Omega} f \phi
\end{equation*}

for every $\phi \in C^1((0,T);W^{1,s'}(\Omega))$ where $\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s'}=1$

**QUESTION:**

> If
>   $$
> \psi(s)
> := \begin{cases} 
> n  &\text{if } s>n\\
> s  &\text{if } -n\le s \le n\\
> -n &\text{if } s<-n
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   can we choose the test function for $(\star)$ to be: $\psi(v)1_{[0,\tau]}$, where $1_{[0,\tau]}$ is the indicator function for any $\tau \le T$ ? If the answer is negative, then **can we assume sufficiently better regularity for $\phi$ in order to allow this specific test function?**

I'm having a hard time getting my head around the regularity of $\phi$ and now with the indicator function also involved, I'm getting more confused.